# Viewport height and .css()

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, viewport

What I'm trying to achieve is to get the browser's viewport height and add it to several classes of my css. So far I have this:

Get viewport height:

```
var width = $(window).width();
var height = $(window).height();
```

Add to css

```
$('divOne').css({"height": " *viewport height* "});
$('divTwo').css({"top": " *viewport height* "});
$('divThree').css({"top": " *viewport height* + 200px"});
$('divTwo').css({"top": " *viewport height* + 400px "});
```

Sample:

[image: Sample]

It would be really great if someone could provide some working piece of code here. My coding skills are very limited.

Comment: Have you tried (very nearly) the code you've posted? Other than the fact you need to do the math outside of the string literals, it looks about right.

Comment: hint: `$('.divThree').css('top', height + 200);`

Comment: Yes, the syntax thing. That was of my main problems :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks about right to me, except you have to do the math outside of the string literals, and because you're using classes, you need a class selector (e.g., `".divOne"`, not "divOne"), e.g.:

```
var width = $(window).width();
var height = $(window).height();
$('.divOne').css({"height": height + "px"});
$('.divTwo').css({"top": height + "px"});
$('.divThree').css({"top": (height + 200) + "px"});
$('.divTwo').css({"top": (height + 400) + "px"});
```

You probably also want to give divs two through four height, because otherwise they'll only be as tall as their content. And you need to be certain that the script operating on the divs is **after** the divs in the markup, so that they exist when the code runs. (Or use jQuery's `ready` event, but there's no need for that if you control where the script tags go.)

Here's an example that adds heights, etc.: [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/ifuseq/1) | [Live Source](http://jsbin.com/ifuseq/1/edit)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Div Height And Such</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="divOne">divOne</div>
  <div class="divTwo">divTwo</div>
  <div class="divThree">divThree</div>
  <div class="divFour">divFour</div>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  var width = $(window).width();
  var height = $(window).height();
  $('.divOne').css({"height": height + "px"});
  $('.divTwo').css({
    "top": height + "px",
    "height": "200px"
  });
  $('.divThree').css({
    "top": (height + 200) + "px",
    "height": "200px"
  });
  $('.divTwo').css({
    "top": (height + 400) + "px",
    "height": "200px"
  });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 $('.divOne').css({
     "height": $(window).height()
 })
```

Try that... Remember the . Before divOne

Comment: Nice catch on the missing dots, +1, but other than that, this doesn't really answer the question...

Answer (score 1):

Is that what you're asking for?

```
var height = $(window).height();
$('.divOne').css({"height": height+"px"});
$('.divTwo').css({"height":  height+"px"});
$('.divTwo').css({"top":  height+"px"});
$('.divThree').css({"top": height+200});
$('.divTwo').css({"top":  height + 400});
```

Comment: you might also consider adding "position:absolute" css property to the divs or changing "top" to "margin-top"

Answer (score 1):

Choose whichever suits you the best. I suggest pure JavaScript with variables.

```
// NO VARIABLES
  // pure JavaScript
  document.getElementById("divOne").style.height =
      document.documentElement.clientHeight;
  document.getElementById("divOne").style.height =
      document.documentElement.clientHeight;
  document.getElementById("divOne").style.height =
      parseFloat(document.documentElement.clientHeight) + 200 + "px";
  document.getElementById("divOne").style.height =
      parseFloat(document.documentElement.clientHeight) + 400 + "px";

  // jQuery
  $("#divOne").style.height = $(window).height();
  $("#divTwo").style.height = $(window).height();
  $("#divThree").style.height = parseFloat($(window).height()) + 200 + "px";
  $("#divFour").style.height = parseFloat($(window).height()) + 200 + "px";

// WITH VARIBLES
  // pure JavaScript   <-- SUGGESTED
    var viewportHeight = parseFloat(document.documentElement.clientHeight);
    document.getElementById("divOne").style.height = viewportHeight + "px";
    document.getElementById("divTwo").style.height = viewportHeight + "px";
    document.getElementById("divThree").style.height =
        viewportHeight + 200 + "px";
    document.getElementById("divFour").style.height =
        viewportHeight + 400 + "px";
  // jQuery
    var viewportHeight = parseFloat($(window).height());
    $("#divOne").style.height = viewportHeight + "px";
    $("#divTwo").style.height = viewportHeight + "px";
    $("#divThree").style.height = viewportHeight + 200 + "px";
    $("#divFour").style.height = viewportHeight + 400 + "px";
```